# DAG graph representation in json and java

Tags: java, json, graph

So far I have used the folowing structure of DAG graph in python:

```
G = {

   's': {'a': 1, 'd': 7},

   'a': {'b': 3, 'c': 5},

   'b': {'d': 2},

   'c': {'e': 6, 'g': 8},

   'd': {'e': 3, 'g': 5},

   'e': {'g': 4},

   'g': {}

   }
```

where G is graph, "a", "b" ... are nodes, and numbers are weights. For example from node "c" to "g" there is a edge with weight 8.
My question is how to represent this structure in json in order to use it later with a graph search algorithm written in java? What should be the structure of java class containing this graph? I would like to use it with gson library.

Comment: are you asking about a JSON representation or a java POJO/BEAN representation?

Comment: Well, both cases are interesting.